# Reversing the counting direction of a counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reverse the counter of the following count but I don't know how to do it.

My dataframe looks like this (adf):

| Visit - ID | Pos(int) | Title(str) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| randomnumber1 | 1 | rstring |
| randomnumber1 | 2 | rstring |
| randomnumber2 | 1 | rstring |
| randomnumber2 | 2 | rstring |
| randomnumber2 | 3 | rstring |

My code looks like the following:

```
bdf = (adf.assign(col=adf.groupby('Visit - ID').cumcount()+1)
   .set_index(['Visit - ID','col'])
   .unstack('col')
   .sort_index(level=(1,0), axis=1)
)

bdf.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x,y in bdf.columns]
```

Output:

| Visit - ID | Pos 1 | Pos 2 | Pos 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| randomnumber1 | 2 | 1 | NaN |
| randomnumber2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| randomnumber3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| randomnumber4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| randomnumber5 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

So the counting is reverse. How do I correct the 'counting direction' so that it looks like the following?

| Visit - ID | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| randomnumber1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| randomnumber2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| randomnumber3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| randomnumber4 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| randomnumber5 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code with example data directly in code - as `df = DataFrame(....)` - so we could simply copy and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumcount(ascending=False)`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
})

df['cc_asc'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=True)
df['cc_desc'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=False)

df
#    id  cc_asc  cc_desc
# 0   1       0        1
# 1   1       1        0
# 2   2       0        2
# 3   2       1        1
# 4   2       2        0
```